# Selecting rows created up to 30 seconds ago in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Say I want to find orders made recently. I am trying this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE time < now() - interval '30 second';
```

This doe not work (It does not select any row.) although the following works:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE time < now();
```

Do I need to use a fixed time variable? Like:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE time < '2018-07-01 12:00:00' - interval '30 second';
```

I am guessing that I should not use now() in statements because it can be changing during operations ...

Comment: Are you sure that data which you selected under right condition? Because now() - interval '30 seconds' works pretty fine.

Comment: @MaximKasyanov Got it! Gordon was right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have the comparison in the wrong direction:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE time > now() - interval '30 second';
```

This returns values in the last 30 seconds.

This assumes that `time` is of an appropriate date type for the comparison.